# How to apply .htaccess in a node.js (express) application?

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, express

I have a node.js express application and I want to authenticate users using .htaccess (part of the requirement). I have added the initial .htaccess code however, it is not working.

Here is a snapshot of my code directory structure:
[Code Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHYfx.png)

Here is the code snippet of my .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please Enter Password"
AuthBasicProvider file pam
AuthUserFile ./.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile ./.groups
Require group admins
```

I have two other files .htpassword and .groups that includes the password and groups.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is kinda strange requirement to me. Mainly because .htaccess is Apache specific. Do you asking how to configure Apache as a reverse proxy to you node app? Or do you want express to respect .htaccess configs?

Comment: That was exactly I was thinking. .htaccess is Apache specific and not sure how to integrate with express. Yes I was hoping to know how to make express work with .htaccess configs.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is Apache specific.

If you want to use a library to do authentication, check [basic-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth).

An example can be found in this article here: https://www.taniarascia.com/basic-authentication-for-an-express-node-app-htpasswd/